Need help with an original wallet on XP
I have an old windows XP machine with my wallet.dat file and the programmes were deleted but are still on the registry (Original Satoshi Client) but can't access them or don't know how. I've saved wallet.dat file on a separate hard drive and downloaded the bitcoin core on a different computer, but it won't work it says doesn't recognise the path. Tried an older version of bitcoin core, but it says corrupt file. Any advice at all please? Surely I can get the info off the registry?
